# htaccess configuration for subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

How should I reconfigure my current htaccess to work for my subdomain? It works for my local setup but not when I upload my files to my subdomain. I can access my site locally through `http://localhost/~myUsername/mySiteFolder/` and I want to upload my files to my subdomain so I can access it like this `http://api.myOnlineSite.com/mySiteFolder`

Current htaccess on my Mac OS local server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~myUsername/mySiteFolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried changing the RewriteBase to `api.myOnlineSite.com/mySiteFolder/` but it doesnt work and shows `The requested URL /mySiteFolder/index.php was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess on your subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mySiteFolder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`RewriteBase` contains relative path from `DocumentRoot` without domain name.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. However, I have this folder in my subdomain I cannot access still but works on the localhost. The directory is /mySiteFolder/CMS/index.php which doesn't have any htaccess of its own. Does the htaccess on the mySiteFolder affect it?

Comment: No child .htaccess always overrides parent directory .htaccess.

Comment: So do you mean I should put .htaccess file on CMS folder and RewriteEngine off?

Comment: You don't even need .htaccess in `cms` folder